How do I type hint a function using TypedDict that mutates a dictionary in Python?
I am defining a function that takes a dictionary as an input, and does some operations on it that creates a new key/value pair and modifies one existing value's type.
I have a TypedDict for both the input and output of the function:
from typing import TypedDict

class MyDict(TypedDict):
    field_1: int
    field_2: str
    field_3: float

class InputDict(MyDict):
    field_4: str

class OutputDict(MyDict):
    field_4: bytes
    field_5: bytes

def transform_dict(input: list[InputDict]) -> list[OutputDict]:
    output = input.copy()
    for x in output:
        x["field_4"] = x["field_4"].encode()
        x["field_5"] = "some_stuff".encode()
    return output

My linter is complaining about the lines where I do the transformation of field_4 and field_5, which makes sense because output is a copy of a type list[InputDict]. What is the best / type-safe way to do this? I understand why it's complaining but I'm can't figure out how to fix it.

typing.cast

Actually, this is kind of unsafe. You are mutating the input dictionaries because list.copy is a shallow copy. This will be unexpected for a caller as their InputDict elements will suddenly become OutputDict.

@nneonneo that could be true in general, but in this case all types contained in the dict are immutable, so mutating its copy will not affect original dict.

@matszwecja: um, no. input is a list. output will be a new list where every element refers to the corresponding element in the first list. Therefore modifying each dict in output will directly affect the dicts in input.

Right, I've read the initial description which doesn't mention the lists present in code and went with that.

yeah sorry for the confusion, i'm doing stuff with lists of dicts here, probably should've made that clearer

Note that it isn't type safe to override InputDict's field_4 in OutputDict. Making OutputDict a direct subclass of MyDict is probably a better choice.

Thanks, that was a mistake on my part, just updated the question

A function named transform_dict probably shouldn't be responsible for iterating over a list of dicts. Define Callable[[InputDict], OutputDict] first, then the desired function is just a simply [transform_dict(x) for x in input].

Actually, this is kind of unsafe. You are mutating the input dictionaries because list.copy is a shallow copy. This will be unexpected for a caller as their InputDict elements will suddenly become OutputDict.
Your best and safest bet will be to make new objects:
output: list[OutputDict] = []
for x in input:
    output.append({
        **x,
        "field_4": x["field_4"].encode(),
        ...
    })
return output

or more concisely as a comprehension:
return [{**x, "field_4": x["field_4"].encode(), ...} for x in input]


yeah this is fair, I was hoping to avoid this as it felt a bit more verbose than my first implementation but it's probably the safest way to do it. Thanks

Or, with list comprehension: [OutputDict(**x, field_4 = x['field_4'].encode(), ...) for x in input]. Depends on the type checker, this may or may not pass type checking.

@InSync actually I think Pyright is right here for rejecting your code: if you actually run it you will get TypeError: OutputDict got multiple values for keyword argument 'field_4'. You can't pass duplicate keys to functions, but you can pass duplicate keys when unpacking. Your comprehension works if we use unpacking instead: return [{**x, "field_4": x['field_4'].encode(), ...} for x in input]

Oops, thanks for the catch. I meant to write OutputDict({**x, 'field_4': ..., ...}).
